# MySql trigger insert new entry with wrong timestamp

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have an old database with version 5.0.95 (which unfortunately I cannot upgrade).

In this database I have a table `clientes_states`:

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes_states` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1239670 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
```

For each change of a client state, **a new entry is generated.** From this reason this table is huge, which makes it complicated to achieve last state of all clients.

In order to **access easily the current state of each client**, I created the following table, and added a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE `actual_clients_states` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `client_id` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21022 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER clients_states_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON clientes_states FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO actual_clients_states (client_id, state_id) 
  VALUES (new.client_id, new.state_id)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE state_id=NEW.state_id;
```

I have two databases, one for testing and one for staging.
From some reason, the `updated_at` field is updated with wrong date (almost a month ago) on the staging server, but works fine on the testing server.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: *From some reason, the updated_at field is updated with wrong date (almost a month ago) on the staging server* No, it simply stayes unchanged. Add `'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` option to the column definition.

Comment: I guess you refer to table `actual_clients_states`?

Comment: of course, this is the only table with `updated_at` column.